# How should we ask questions that rely on homophones?

Tags: discussion, questions

Some types of riddles work when asked verbally but not when written down because the catch is that a certain word uses a homophone with a different spelling. How should these kinds of questions be asked?

[Here's one possible solution](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=One%20night,%20a%20king%20and%20a%20queen%20enter%20an%20empty%20room.%20The%20next%20day,%20three%20people%20leave.) (although it's limited to rather short questions).

Comment: What's your link about? 1. Please do not use link shorteners. 2. This seems to be some audio link, but I don't have sound right now so I genuinely don't know what you're trying to convey.

Comment: @Gilles The link is to a Google Translate dictation. I shortened the link so that you can't read the text with the wrong spelling of the homophone.

Answer (score 4):

It may depend on the riddle, but I'm not sure any special treatment is necessary. Homophones are a fairly common feature of riddles and I guess most people (or most people likely to solve the riddle) will be looking for them anyway.

If you think there might still be a problem, one option would be to take a cue from cryptic crossword clues. The convention is to add a phrase such as "we hear". The problem with this kind of approach is that it signposts the fact that the solution depends on a homophone.

Comment: So should we just create a tag for this kind of question and the existence of the tag should alert people that certain words may be spelled incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution would be to provide the riddle as an audio file only, but I am not sure if the existing rules of posting accomodate for that.